# Printing 'flip on short side' on a 'flip on long side' printer

Tags: printing

I have a PDF file that it is in landscape format. Therefore, for a correct double side printing, I would need to 'flip on the short side'.

However, I have a machine that only flips on the long side (because it's an on line printer, for example). So, in order to print correctly the book, I would just need to rotate 180 degrees clockwise every second sheet. How can I do this?

As it sounds like a typical problem, there's got to be a standard solution, rather than rotating each page manually.

Comment: What OS are you using? What printer?  *"because it's an on line printer"* -- How is that relevant (i.e. there are wide and narrow carriage versions of line printers)?  If you're not using a page printer, then you are probably out of luck.  *"I would just need to rotate 180 degrees clockwise"* -- Do you expect different results 180 degrees counter-clockwise?

Comment: I am using Win7. It's relevant since I am connecting to a remote machine, whose OS I ignore, and whose printing GUI has been built by someone, and the 'flipping option' is not there, which means that it is flipped on the long edge and I cannot modify it. 180 degrees rotation counterclockwise is the same, yes, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The free program PFDSAM at pdfsam.org does the job.